# link Azure PowerShell runbook webhook to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, webhooks

I have an Azure powershell runbook, created a webhook for it and I would like to trigger this from SharePoint.
When I try to add the webhook subscription, I get this error message.

```
Add-PnPWebhookSubscription : {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Failed to 
validate the notification URL 'https://xxx.webhook.we.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=zzzz'."}}}
```

According to my research, this is because the webhook has to return a validation token. Also, this seems to be passed in the URL of the validation request towards the webhook.

How can I extract this? I have access to the WebhookData input, but it doesn't contain such a property. I added a validationtoken parameter, but that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> Before a new subscription is created, SharePoint sends a request with
> a validation token in the body of the request to the service URL
> provided. Your service must respond to this request by returning the
> validation token.
>
> If your service fails to validate the request in this way, the
> subscription is not created.

Here is the document for more details

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/lists/create-subscription#url-validation

Comment: This part I know and mentioned in the post too. The question is how to achieve this with a webhook of an Azure PowerShell Runbook.